# How to convert fabricjs object to different file formats?

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

How to convert fabricjs object into different file formats like BMP, JPEG, PNG?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 var _base64 = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

supported file formates are as follow

- PNG
- JPEG
- BMP